# Разработка программ для XP Python

Tags: python

Какую версию python использоваться, чтобы программа работала на Windows XP? В частности библиотека Matplotlib

Comment: ту версию которую можно установить на wxp смотри на сайте Python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491161/unable-to-install-python-3-5-within-windows-xp-professional

Comment: Берите версию Python 3.4 и пробуйте. Python 3.5 и выше не поддерживает Windows XP (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZwC7.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если требуется разработать программу под XP с использованием данной библиотеки, то попробуй выше написанное, если использование программы с данной библиотекой, то попробуй сперва из *.py конвертировать в *.exe и уже exeшник пробуйте запустить на Windows XP